# Display "Pseudocode" instead of "Algorithm" in \begin{algorithm}

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

Instead of the "Algorithm" which gets **automatically added** when used with `\usepackage{algorithm}`, I want it to display as "Pseudocode", How can I do this? :
[image: this]

Like the "Pseudocode" written in this:
[image]

The latex code for Fig 1 is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{alg:euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Statex Input: Something
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please make your example compilable?

Comment: Please check now @TeXnician

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\floatname{algorithm}{Pseudocode}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{algorithm}{2}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{alg:euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Statex Input: Something
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```